# Makefile: computed variable name

Tags: makefile

In the following example Makefile:

```
EXTENS := .c .C .cc .c++ .cpp .cxx
SOURCES := 1.c 2.C 3.cc 4.c++ 5.cpp 6.cxx
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES)

REPLACE_EXTENS = $(foreach f,$(EXTENS),$(eval $(1) := $(patsubst %$(f),%.o,$($(1)))))
$(call REPLACE_EXTENS, OBJECTS)

all:
    @echo $(SOURCES)
    @echo $(OBJECTS)
```

I expect the line `@echo $(OBJECTS)` to output:

```
1.o 2.o 3.o 4.o 5.o 6.o
```

However it outputs nothing. What I am doing wrong and what would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: `$(eval ...)` doesn't make sense here.

Comment: `what would be the correct way to do it` You should probably elaborate on what you are trying to solve with this.

Comment: @user657267, I thought it was pretty obvious -- create list of object files from list of source files

Comment: @InnocentBystander I meant at a deeper level, because it looks like something that could be solved by implicit rules instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$(call REPLACE_EXTENS, OBJECTS)` into `$(call REPLACE_EXTENS,OBJECTS)`. No whitespace between arguments for call.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to to do this is to throw out the EXTENS and REPLACE_EXTENS call completely, and write:

```
SOURCES := 1.c 2.C 3.cc 4.c++ 5.cpp 6.cxx
OBJECTS := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES))

all:
        @echo $(SOURCES)
        @echo $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Thank you. Although it does not answer my question, this is a very good alternative solution. I wish I could accept both answers -- short of that, I've upvoted your answer.